# Hibernate-java8 appears to not works with conversion from MSSQL smalldatetime to java.time.Instant

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am working in a project with Gradle, Spring 4 and Hibernate.

I wanted to pickup from Microsoft SQL Server Express (64-bit) version 11.0.3156.0 a date column with type smalldatetime.

This a very simple class

```
   @Entity
    public class TimeSlot {
      @Id
      private int dayOfWeek;
      protected Instant start;
      protected Instant end;

      public TimeSlot(){
      }
      ... getters and setters ...
    }
```

And when I ran this I got this exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:458)
    at com.sample.persistance.PersistenceUtils.listAndCast(PersistenceUtils.java:15)
    at com.sample.concordia.chat.persistence.TimeSlotRepository.retrieveTimeSlots(TimeSlotRepository.java:60)
    at com.sample.concordia.utils.EstadosPilotoService.getPilotos(EstadosPilotoService.java:118)
    at com.sample.concordia.chat.service.ChatService.messageReceived(ChatService.java:89)
    at com.sample.concordia.chat.service.ChatService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e186c88a.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:649)
    at com.sample.concordia.chat.service.ChatService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$72a00849.messageReceived(<generated>)
    at com.sample.concordia.chat.service.ChatSocketHandler.handleTextMessage(ChatSocketHandler.java:25)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.AbstractWebSocketHandler.handleMessage(AbstractWebSocketHandler.java:43)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.WebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(WebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.handleTextMessage(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.access$000(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter$3.onMessage(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter$3.onMessage(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:79)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.sendMessageText(WsFrameBase.java:393)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processDataText(WsFrameBase.java:494)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processData(WsFrameBase.java:289)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processInputBuffer(WsFrameBase.java:130)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.onDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:60)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler$WsReadListener.onDataAvailable(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:203)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractServletInputStream.onDataAvailable(AbstractServletInputStream.java:198)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractProcessor.upgradeDispatch(AbstractProcessor.java:96)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:663)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:279)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:306)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2969)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1696)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1628)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1515)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:726)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:921)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:353)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1909)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:311)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 0000059F
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:806)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:328)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:237)
    ... 59 more
```

And I found that the serialization issue was from hibernate, who cannot convert to java.time.* classes.

So I updated to Hibernate 5.0.5. These are my gradle dependecies:

```
compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.9.1.RELEASE')
compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.0.5.Final')
compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-java8:5.0.4.Final')
compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.0.5.Final')
```

As I see in https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8844 , just adding **org.hibernate:hibernate-java8:5.0.4.Final** there is no need of javax.persistence.Converter, just map your entity with java.time.Instant or other from java.time and should work fine.

But is not my case, I still got '*org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize*'.

Please, can anyone help me? there is some misconfiguration?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you remember if you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: unfortunately no